# C# IText7 HTML inside a Table Cell

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext, itext7

i try to put HTML in a cell, but the border seems double lines:

```
 cell = new Cell();
                    var elementsList = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(sectioncontent);

                    foreach (IElement e in elementsList)
                    {
                        cell.Add((IBlockElement)e);
                    }
                    cell.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
                    table.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED).AddCell(cell);
```

with html like this (caught from CKEditor and i put in a database):

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

================================ end

```
String HTML = "<p>Overview&#160;line1</p>"
        + "<p>Overview&#160;line2</p><p>Overview&#160;line3</p>"
        + "<p>Overview&#160;line4</p><p>Overview&#160;line4</p>"
        + "<p>Overview&#160;line5&#160;</p>";
            String CSS = "p { font-family: Cardo; }";

            cell = new Cell();
            //cell.Add(new Paragraph(s));
            ElementList elementsList = XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(HTML, CSS);

            foreach (IElement e in elementsList)
            {
                cell.Add((IBlockElement)e);
            }
            cell.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            table.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED).AddCell(cell);


            document.Add(table);
```

but it raise exception:
Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.Paragraph' to type 'iText.Layout.Element.IElement'.

How to workaround?
regards and thanks

Comment: You use a mix of iText 7 and iText 5. E.g. `XMLWorkerHelper` is not an iText 7 class. Please use the `HtmlConverter` from the iText 7 add-on pdfHTML instead.

Comment: Thanks, but the html is converted as a whole. How if i want only a cell of a table has content HTML?

Comment: *"Thanks, but the html is converted as a whole. How if i want only a cell of a table has content HTML?"* - similar to your mixed attempt above. `HtmlConverter` has a `convertToElements` method...

Comment: Unfortunately, the result for html table is so messy, like there is two lines, and one row jump to the top...

Comment: You might want to [edit] your question to illustrate this new issue.

Comment: I change the ellpadding="0" and cellspacing="0", and now its okay..thanks